# Regex: Solving regex with negation

Tags: regex, ubuntu, negation

I have a file where inside it I want to filter the line that has no node_module string.
So given the file:

```
./sec24_proj31/node_modules/eslint-plugin-react/lib/rules/no-did-update-set-state.js:componentDidUpdate
./sec08_proj20_burger_builder/src/components/UI/Modal/Modal.js:componentDidUpdate
```

I was trying with these regex but they don't work:

```
grep -E 'componentDidUpdate' test | grep -E '(?!.*node_modules.*)'
grep -E '(?!.*node_modules.*)componentDidUpdate' test'
```

In case of the first one the idea is that the second regex filters the first output but I was trying many different things and neither worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you have no anchor on your negative lookahead, so it can match anywhere in the first string after the `n` in `node_modules`. You can fix that by adding a start-of-string anchor (`^`) i.e.

```
grep -E 'componentDidUpdate' test | grep -E '^(?!.*node_modules)'
```

Alternatively you can combine the two regexes (with the anchor) and using a `.*` in front of `componentDidUpdate` to allow it to occur anywhere in the string:

```
grep -E '^(?!.*node_modules).*componentDidUpdate' test'
```

**Note:**

1. the `.*` after `node_modules` in the lookahead is not required.
2. You may want to put word breaks (`\b`) around `node_modules` and/or `componentDidUpdate` to ensure that (for example) you don't match against `anode_modules` or `nocomponentDidUpdate`. For `node_modules` it may be sufficient to just surround it with `/` characters.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the comments, I've added a note to that effect.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I was trying with both and they didn't work.

Comment: @PabloN can you give some more details as to how they "didn't work"?